# can jQuery.post method submit the form to next step?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am looking for `jQuery.post` method. I am getting information from our customers in five steps , lets say for first step I am getting information from my customer and saving those to DB using `jQuery.post` method, once data saved successfully then I want to `submit` the form to next step but I am not able to do. Any suggestion please?

Code:

```
if (error == false) {
jQuery.post("<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/plugins/mail-masta/inc/campaign_save.php", {
    camp: camp_name,
    sname: se‌​nder_name,
    semail: sender_email,
    step: camp_step
}, function (resp) {
    if (resp != '') {
        alert("something went wrong"); //jQuery("form:first").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Data inserted"); // jQuery("form:first").submit();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: _but I am not able to do_ - can you show us what's been done till now?

Comment: if(error == false){    
jQuery.post("<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/plugins/mail-masta/inc/campaign_save.php",{camp:camp_name,sname:sender_name,semail:sender_email,step:camp_step}, function (resp){ if (resp != '')
{alert("something went wrong"); //jQuery("form:first").submit();  }
else {alert("Data inserted"); // jQuery("form:first").submit();
}});}

Comment: Can you also paste your HTML code in your question?

Comment: Within the else block of ur `$.Post()` should be the place where you need to redirect the page after alerting the user that "data inserted". may be a delay after the alert should be fine in order for the user to see the alert and then the page redirection.

Comment: @dreamweiver It's not redirect, I think the OP wants to `submit` the form after the `$.POST` request is completed (check the commented code)

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger: well even that should not be a prob, as he will have to call `$( "#target" ).submit();` (target is the id of the form). **REF:https://api.jquery.com/submit/**.

Comment: Yes I want to submit the form once data inserted properly. @dreamweiver: the method you mentioned above doesn't work for me..

Comment: @sudhanshu: what do u mean by not working ? after the alert the form is not getting submitted ? is there any error at this point in console ?

Comment: I did it in some other way and it works.. but i really appreciate your help my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can go to next step simply by setting `location.href` (THIS IS NOT GOOD SOLUTION):

```
jQuery.post("<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/plugins/mail-masta/inc/campaign_save.php", {
        camp: camp_name,
        sname: se‌​ nder_name,
        semail: sender_email,
        step: camp_step
    }, function (resp) {
        location.href = '/nextstep.html';
    });
```

However, if you DO have 5 pages, just don't use `jQuery.post` -- use `<form method="POST">` to submit data and let the server redirect you to the next step is more proper.

Another way is to modify the page with javascript after you've done with `jQuery.post` so that the browser doesn't have to load the next step. That's why you are using JavaScript and Ajax.